# Change top of Popup box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

In My code I am using Smarty to display a pop-up in (.tpl) file.
I am using following function for pop-up.

```
popUpLightBox( $intWidth, $intHeight, url, 'Title of popup');
```

in my code i am using CLightBox.class.js Liabrary. In which the Top and Left of Pop-up
window is set internally by CLightBox.class.js liabrary.
and due to this each time i ain't get fixed position of pop-up. CLightBox.class.js use
below code to set left and top.
`this.intLeft   = (Math.round((this.intViewportWidth - this.intCurrentWidth)/2) + 250);

        this.intTop     = (Math.round((this.intViewportHeight - this.intCurrentHeight)/2) + 192);`
Here, viewport width and height is set according to the data rows in the tpl file  .

Does anybody can help me to reset its Top by using jQuery or using javascript.
Any type of help is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: ok wait I will provide it.